# Move folder to another existing git repository and keep the history

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a `Repo A` with multiple folders , I'd like to move just a particular folder , say `folder1` with all it's commit history to an already existing `Repo B` so that it is `RepoB/folder1`.

Comment: The "history" is associated with the *repo*.  It sounds like your best bet might be to clone the repo, then simply delete the stuff you're uninterested in.  Better yet, create a new branch, and delete everything you're not interested in.  You might also be interested in [rewriting history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)

Comment: @paulsm4 How do I move the folder after isolating it in a new branch?

Comment: You don't ("move the folder"). History, in Git, is commits. The commits are the history. To add more history, add commits. To keep existing history, keep existing commits. If you turn some history (of everything) into a subset history (of only stuff in some folder), you have created a whole new history, different from the original history: that's fine, but those are just those commits. Put them into another repository if you like.

Comment: @Akash janardhan S - Q: How do I move the folder?  A: Easy: `git mv old_stuff new_place/`.  Look [here](http://st-on-it.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-move-folders-between-git.html)